# MediaElement locks file after playback

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

It looks like System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement somehow locks every single file played until program sutdown. Usage more or less as follows:

```
MediaElement player;
player.Source = new Uri(path);
player.Play();
player.Close();
```

After playing several files i tried to delete them in explorer - thay are reappearing. Deleting them from code (System.IO.File.Delete()) rise no exceptions, but files aren`t deleting either. Only after closing the app all deleted files are actualy being deleted.

Is it known behavior and how it`s possible to force MediaElement to relese files played?

Comment: Did you tried setting source to `null`?

Comment: I've seen the same thing. I stopped using MediaElement because of it. I did temporarily come up with a hack solution which was to use Handle.exe to force unlock the file, but it wasn't a great solution.